# Remote IBM MQ monitoring from power-shell scripts

Tags: powershell, ibm-mq

I am trying to get queue depth for remote IBM MQ using PowerShell script/commands. Seems it is not working correctly, please help.

Powershell script:

```
{
$myremoteconns = New-WMQQmgrConnDef -Name T.test.TEST.QM1 -Hostname abcd_testhost01 -Port 1111 -Channel T.test.MQMQ.TESTCHN

$qm = Get-WMQQueueManager -Connections $myremoteconns | where {$_.Name -like 'T.test.TEST.QM1'}
```

Error message received:

```
Error CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Get-WMQQueueManager], arameterBindingValidationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,WebSphereMQ.GetWMQQueueManager
```

Already installed WebSphere MQ - Windows PowerShell Library from below.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24017698

Thanks

Comment: Can you set the following environment variable and run the command again.
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
Setting the above env variable will provide more debug statements and it might help

Comment: Your command has to be $myremoteconns += New-WMQQmgrConnDef -Name T.test.TEST.QM1 -Hostname abcd_testhost01 -Port 1111 -Channel T.test.MQMQ.TESTCHN

Answer (score 1):

To get remote queue manager information,you have to follow the following steps as stated in the powershellcookbook.pdf which comes along with MO74.

```
PS C:\> $qmconns = @()
PS C:\> $qmconns += New-WMQQmgrConnDef -Name DALEQM -Hostname dlane.hursley.ini.com -Channel SVRCN -Port 1414
PS C:\> $qmconns += New-WMQQmgrConnDef -Name CENTQM -Hostname sysserv.boulder.ini.com -Channel SVRCN -Port 1418
PS C:\>
PS C:\> $qmgrs = Get-WMQQueueManager –Connections $qmconns
PS C:\> $remoteqmgrs = Get-WMQQueueManager –Connections $qmconns | Where { $_.Hostname –like “*.hursley.ini.com” }
```

In your first command "+" is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you will never get the current queuedepth out of a remote queue - it does not have one since it is a pointer to another qmgr.
To be sure it would be necessary to see the MQ Completion and Reason Code.

Comment: yes , it is part of the code and planning to integrate it . Is there any other way to get MQ depth for remote queue from windows shell .

Comment: @dalelane I seen your blog about this , http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?page_id=9 .
can you help here ?